# Export a list of fields

Tags: list, export, field, odoo, odoo-10

How can I export a list of all fields that are displayed on "Settings > Technical > Database structure > Fields" (web?debug#min=1&limit=80&view_type=list&model=ir.model.fields&action=15&menu_id=4) to csv or excel ?

Comment: You can use Action -> Export , Please choose the all items in tree view

Comment: @VishnuVaNnErI Thank You, worked! Please add as an answer :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Use Export Option In Action

Action --> Export.

Choose all line items in Tree view[image]